# Set a part of a draggable div as undraggable

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

I'm using the Angular Material CDK, in particular the drag and drop feature,
I was wondering if there was any way to set one of the children div as undraggable, while still allowing the parent div to be dragged ?

```
    <div cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div cdkDrag class="section" *ngFor="let section of sections">
            <sectionComponent dynamically appended trough a factory>
        </div>
    </div>
```

each section component is draggable into the parent cdkDropList.
Here is the strucure of one section.

```
    <div class="sectionContainer">
        <div class="sectionParam">
        </div>
        <div class="sectionContent">
        </div>
    </div>
```

What i want is to be able to drag the entire section, but only when the origin of the drag comes from the sectionContent div. I have some sliders in the paramSection causing problems with the drag and drop feature.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you show us your code, so we can help ?

Comment: I added some code, hope it helps :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For people looking to do the same, drag n drop provide a directive. Use [cdkDragHandle] on a child div to create a block that will handle the drag of the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it exists a ckdDragDisabled property:

```
<div [cdkDragDisabled]="your_condition()">
```

you have the documentation here

https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#disabled-dragging

Comment: It doesn't work in my situation cause i don't want to disable the dragging of the entire element, only a portion of it. I added some code to explain it better.
I have sliders in the paramSection of my draggable div, which causes problems with the drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for a solution to this problem - per Bryan Sullivan's answer here: [Is it possible to disable dragging on a sub-element of cdkDrag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62083105/is-it-possible-to-disable-dragging-on-a-sub-element-of-cdkdrag)

Just add `(mousedown)="$event.stopPropagation()"` to any child elements that you don't want to be draggable.

```
    <div class="sectionContainer">
        <div class="sectionParam" (mousedown)="$event.stopPropagation()">
            <!-- can't drag this -->
        </div>
        <div class="sectionContent">
            <!-- can drag this -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is not working, can you check once, instead $event.preventDefault() is working as expected.