# Is it possible to disable dragging on a sub-element of cdkDrag?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I am using Angular CDK drag-drop from Angular Material (see documentation [here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview)). I was wondering if it is possible to **disable dragging on a sub-element of `cdkDrag`**. The problem is it is impossible to select what is written in an `input` of the draggable element using the mouse.

So, what I want to do is to **disable dragging on all the `input` which are under the element which has the `cdkDrag` directive**.

I have tried using:

- **cdkDragHandle**: that would put the dragging on a specific element, not what I want to do here
- **cdkDragDisabled**: that would disable dragging the whole element, not what I want to do here

Here is what my code looks like:

```html
<div cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div *ngFor="let element of array" cdkDrag>
        <div>
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Input 1</mat-label>
                <input matInput type="text">
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Input 2</mat-label>
                <input matInput type="number">
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Comment: you can add a delay of,e.g. 150 miliseconds or 200 milliseconds`<div *ngFor="let element of array" cdkDrag [cdkDragStartDelay]="150" >` This give you a change to select the text

Comment: @Eliseo It doesn't really do what I want and sets a delay on the main div as well. Thanks for your help, though!

Comment: I know it's too late, I just answer to a question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62304645/display-and-update-formgroup-inside-formarray and you can use one variable "itemselected" and [cdkDragDisabled]="itemselected==i"

Comment: @Gaetitan Did you ever find a proper solution for this?

Comment: @StringName Unfortunately I didn't, so I left it as is.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can stop the mousedown event propagation on your form fields. Add the following to the form field element: (mousedown)="$event.stopPropagation()".

This stops the drag event from happening when you try to click into a form field and lets you interact normally with that form field.

```
<div cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div *ngFor="let element of array" cdkDrag>
        <div>
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Input 1</mat-label>
                <input matInput type="text"(mousedown)="$event.stopPropagation()">
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Input 2</mat-label>
                <input matInput type="number"(mousedown)="$event.stopPropagation()">
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks very much!

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple workaround:

app.component.css

```css
.display-none {
  display: none;
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<div cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div *ngFor="let element of array" cdkDrag>
        <div>
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Input 1</mat-label>
                <input matInput type="text" cdkDrag cdkDragPreviewClass="display-none">
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Input 2</mat-label>
                <input matInput type="number" cdkDrag cdkDragPreviewClass="display-none">
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Just add `cdkDrag cdkDragPreviewClass="display-none"` to your input elements. That should help you.

Comment: Looks like ```cdkDrag``` on the input makes the input draggable.

Comment: That's right, but it'll be destroyed once there's a `display: none` style.

Comment: I tried your solution but it seems that ```cdkDragPreviewClass``` doesn't exist. Did you mean ```<input cdkDrag *cdkDragPreview class="display_none"```>?

Comment: Make sure to add `.display-none {
  display: none;
}` to component styles